# How to convert window coordinates relative to a specific view?

Tags: iphone, uiview, coordinates

Example: I have a CGPoint in window coordinates:

```
CGPoint windowPoint = CGPointMake(220.0f, 400.0f);
```

There is `aView` which has a superview in a superview in a superview. Somewhere deep in the view hierarchy, probably even transformed a few times.

When you get a UITouch, you can ask it for -locationInView: and it will return the coordinates relative to that view.

I need pretty much the same thing. Is there an easy way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found a really easy solution:

```
[self.aView convertPoint:windowPoint fromView:self.window];
```

Comment: There are several conversion routines like that one provided by UIView.  They're all described in the UIView class reference guide.  http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/convertPoint:fromView:

Comment: Handy trick if you need to do this for a frame rect, for example for animation, is [sourceView convertRect:targetView.bounds fromView:targetView]; don't use targetView.frame or you'll double add its origin.

Comment: You may use nil instead of self.window, in this case the method converts in base to the  window coordinates

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could iterate through the superview tree, drilling down to subviews by tag, and add or subtract the subview's `frame.origin` values to get to a translated `windowPoint` relative to the view-of-interest's `frame.origin`.