# How to determine if a point in the window's coordinate system is within a view, in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Given a point in the coordinate system of the window, how do you determine if that point is within the bounds of a view?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert window coordinates relative to a specific view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906787/how-to-convert-window-coordinates-relative-to-a-specific-view)

Comment: @shallowThought there's no answer in swift there, so it's not a duplicate

Comment: Sure it's a duplicate. Converting such Objective-C code to Swift is trivial. You still use the same APIs.

Comment: 50 / 50. Peace.

Comment: @rmaddy it's not the same api. that answer is nearly 7 years old, so if you also don't understand the language that the outdated answer is typed in, it becomes non-trivial

Comment: @shoe come on. We are just trying to help here.

Comment: Yes, it is the same API for the same classes. It's just the names are slightly different with Swift 3.

Comment: @shallowThought i saw that question before i posted this one, so no it didn't help me. and just because a question may have helped me doesn't make it an answer to my question or make my question a duplicate

Comment: @shoe You are technically right. Let's keep on coding instead of this. Removed my "duplicate" closing flag 5 comments before btw.

Comment: @shallowThought fair enough. but it wasn't just about the tag, it was about the tag, being voted down 4 times, and being told i was wrong by who i imagine were moderators, when i wasn't wrong

Comment: @EricAya never implied what you're trying to correct

Comment: @shoe Well then I misunderstood, nevermind.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is to use:

```
let pointRelativeToView = view.convert(pointRelativeToWindow, nil)
let pointIsInWindow = view.frame.contains(pointRelativeToView)
```